# MySQL View: Join tables without causing the data to duplicate on every row?

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates, union

I am basically having the exact same problem as here:

[SQL View: Join tables without causing the data to duplicate on every row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042874/sql-view-join-tables-without-causing-the-data-to-duplicate-on-every-row)

Except on that question he was using SQL, and I am using mysql. I am wondering if the same query is possible in mysql. If so, I may have the wrong syntax?

I am trying to do something like

```
select a.name as account_Name, 
   p.description as property_DESCRIPTION, 
   p.address as property_ADDRESS, 
   null as vehicles_DESCRIPTION,
   null as vehicles_MAKE, 
   null as vehicles_MODEL
from Accounts a
    inner join Properties p
        on a.accountid = p.accountid
UNION ALL   
select a.name as account_Name, 
   null as property_DESCRIPTION, 
   null as property_ADDRESS, 
   v.description as vehicles_DESCRIPTION,
   v.make as vehicles_MAKE, 
   v.model as vehicles_MODEL
from Accounts a
    inner join vehicles v
        on a.accountid = v.accountid
```

Here is my actual code:

```
SELECT user.first_name, user.last_name, upi.image_id, NULL AS friends.friend_user_id FROM user 
INNER JOIN user_profile_images as upi ON (user.user_id = upi.user_id) 
UNION 
SELECT user.first_name, user.last_name, NULL AS upi.image_id, friends.friend_user_id FROM user 
INNER JOIN friends ON (user.user_id = friends.user_id) 
WHERE user.user_id = '$profile_id'
```

where I have 3 tables: user, user_profile_images, and friends. Both user_profile_images and friends are related to the user through the user_id. So a user can have multiple profile images as well as multiple friend entries. I can post the table diagrams if it doesnt make sense. But what I want is basically a view of all the info, with fields NULL if they don't apply to the overall view.

If I do the query with 2 tables, either with user and user_profile_images, or user and friends, I get the desired results, but adding the third table gives me duplicate rows.

Comment: SQL is a language, of which MySQL is a particular implementation. There's nothing that's "just SQL". WHen you do `union all`, you force mysql to return all rows from the unioned queries. remove the `all` keyword and mysql eliminate duplicate rows for you.

Comment: Also read about left/right joins as they might be a better solution sometimes.

Comment: Your "actual code" will probably give an error because you don't have the same number of columns in each table - there's a `upi.image_id` in the second `SELECT` but not the first.

Comment: My mistake, I copied a bad chunk of code, updated again with the code that I still can't get to work...

Comment: Your error message is clearly a PHP one ("mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 ...") - can you either do the queries from the MySQL prompt directly (so we can sort out the MySQL problems before moving onto PHP problems), or at least post the PHP code you use to query the database, including the line the error comes from. Also, in the line you use to execute the query, could you do `$con->query('...') or die($con->error)` (or `mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error(...))`) so that we can work out whether the error is in the MySQL or the PHP, and *what exactly* the error is.

Comment: Sure, a direct query gives: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.friend_user_id FROM user INNER JOIN user_profile_images as upi ON (user.user_i' at line 1

Comment: Looks like you're missing an underscore between the `friend` and `user_id` ? i.e.  `friend user_id` -> `friend_user_id`? Also, you don't really need those table names in the column aliases -- `NULL AS image_id` and `NULL AS friend_user_id` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, as @MarcB suggests, is to use `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL`.

However, I have a question for you - why use the `UNION` at all? The following is equivalent, *except* that if (say) account 1 has one property and one vehicle, instead of getting:

```
account_Name   property_DESCRIPTION   vehicles_MAKE
  account1          property1             NULL
  account1           NULL                vehicle1
```

You'll get

```
account_Name   property_DESCRIPTION   vehicles_MAKE
  account1          property1            vehicle1
```

Query:

```
SELECT a.name as account_Name, 
   p.description as property_DESCRIPTION, 
   p.address as property_ADDRESS, 
   v.description as vehicles_DESCRIPTION,
   v.make as vehicles_MAKE, 
   v.model as vehicles_MODEL
FROM Accounts a
LEFT JOIN Properties p
        on a.accountid = p.accountid
LEFT JOIN vehicles v
        on a.accountid = v.accountid
WHERE p.description IS NOT NULL AND v.make IS NOT NULL
```

Note - the last line (IS NOT NULL for both p and v) simulates the 'accounts table' part of the `INNER JOIN` and makes sure that only accounts with at least a property OR a vehicle are shown. Substitute the `id` columns of `p` and `v` there.

Comment: I'm not too experienced with SQL so not sure about other ways to do it, just that the UNION made sense for the question on the other link. I tried removing the ALL from UNION but the query still doesn't seem to work. I tried the left joins you mentioned but I still get duplicate rows. I have updated my question to make it more clear with what's going on.

Comment: What do you mean by "still doesn't seem to work" - you get duplicates, or you get an error (and what error)? Re trying left joins & getting duplicate rows - do you mean that there are some rows where every column is identical? Do they differ in some field that you *haven't* `SELECT`ed? (I can make the symptoms disappear, but there's probably something sick underneat so I'm trying to work out what). Can you give an example of "duplicate rows"? cheers.

Comment: By doesn't work I mean I get an error: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given. Which makes me think the syntax is wrong somehow. Sorry I'm bad at e

Comment: By doesn't work I mean I get an error: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given. Which makes me think the syntax is wrong somehow. Sorry I'm bad at explaining, not exact duplicates. For example: there will be multiple rows, with the same data in the user and user_image_profile columns, but different data in the friends columns. So what I want is for each unique row of data from a table to have its own row, with the columns of other tables being null. Which I am thinking might be inefficient and I'm going about it the wrong way...?

Comment: Doing it this way, I realized that the table is going to multiply by the # of rows in the user_profile_images x the rows in the friends column. So if the user has 4 friends and 7 images, its going to return 28 rows, and if they add another image making it 8, 32 rows. This seems like not the most efficient way to go about this query...would 2 separate queries for the friends and user_profile_images tables be the way to go? Sorry to change the subject but I don't want to waste too much of your time! Just trying to figure out the most efficient way of doing things.

Comment: You are going about it the wrong way - by doing the `NULL` thing you're going to get way more rows than by using a join and having them combined. Of course you will have duplicate `user/user_image_profile` with *different* friends, because a user has one profile but many friends. By asking for an aggregate result, whether by `JOIN` or `UNION`, you will always have this problem. If that bothers you, then do two *separate* select queries (do you actually want them joined anyway? You could do two separate selects and sort by user id on both?)

Comment: Do two separate queries unless you need them joined for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If I were going after data like that where two tables are related by an id on the third I would consider using outer joins.  In the comments of the question you referenced, outer joins were mentioned as a possible solution.  The code for that would look like this.

```
select a.name as account_Name, 
p.description as property_DESCRIPTION,
p.address as property_ADDRESS,
v.description as vehicles_DESCRIPTION,
v.make as vehicles_MAKE, 
v.model as vehicles_MODEL
from accounts a
left outer join properties p on p.accountid = a.accountid
left outer join vehicles v on v.accountid = a.accountid;
```

Here is how the solution was tested.  First I created the three tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `properties` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`accountid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `vehicles` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`accountid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`make` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`model` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Next I inserted data into each table.

```
INSERT INTO `demo`.`accounts` (
`accountid` ,
`name`
)
VALUES (
NULL , 'techport80.com'
);

INSERT INTO `demo`.`properties` (
`id` ,
`accountid` ,
`description` ,
`address`
)
VALUES (
NULL , '1', 'office', '123 may street');

INSERT INTO `demo`.`vehicles` (
`id` ,
`accountid` ,
`description` ,
`make` ,
`model`
)
VALUES (
NULL , '1', 'motorcycle', 'honda', 'shadow'
);
```

At this point if I test the solution, I will receive one row with account, property and vehicle information.

```
INSERT INTO `demo`.`vehicles` (
`id` ,
`accountid` ,
`description` ,
`make` ,
`model`
)
VALUES (
NULL , '1', 'passenger car', 'Ford', 'Mustang'
);
```

Now if I test my solution, I see 2 row, one for each vehicle.  But the two rows are not exactly duplicate.  Though there are some column with the same data.  Most notably, the account information.

```
INSERT INTO `demo`.`properties` (
`id` ,
`accountid` ,
`description` ,
`address`
)
VALUES (
NULL , '1', 'home', '321 yam street'
);
```

Next I added a second address.  Now four rows are returned.  One for each vehicle and one for each address.  But still, none of the rows are duplicate.

Finally I added another vehicle.  This was to cause an off balance of vehicle vs properties.

```
INSERT INTO `demo`.`vehicles` (
`id` ,
`accountid` ,
`description` ,
`make` ,
`model`
)
VALUES (
NULL , '1', 'Van', 'Chev', 'Cargo'
);
```

Now we have 6 rows.  One per each vehicle and each vehicle is also related to two properties.  (So 2 x 3)

Having gone thru this exercise, I wonder if a hierarchical view of the data would be a better model for this data.  Perhaps XML or JSON could be used represent the data.  For this task, you could use a stored function, but I personally would first consider a programming language like PHP, C#, C++, or a slew of others.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I tried the left joins like you said and still got duplicate rows.